# mongoose - Is it possible to dynamically add methods to model at runtime?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I know you can define methods and statics on a schema

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({});
schema.methods.fn = function(){}
```

But is it possible after you've created a model from the schema?

```
var model = mongoose.model(schema);
```

I tried

```
model.schema.methods.fn2 = function(){};
```

but it doesn't work.

I wanted to add certain methods at runtime, and since the only important thing at runtime is the model, and not the schema, I was wondering if you could continue to add methods to the model's internal schema somehow dynamically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can add methods to your mongoose model just like you would any other javascript class.

```
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);

Person.prototype.myMethod = function() {
    console.log(this.toString());
}

var bob = new Person({
    name: 'Bob'
});
myModel.myMethod();
```

Note that capitalizing javascript classes like this is a good convention to follow, it makes it clear to the reader that it's a constructor function that should be called with `new`.

Comment: is this also possible with middleware?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a prototype on any registered model by creating a prototype on the model object.

**In your model definition file**

```
//define your schema
module.exports = mongoose.model('model', schema);
```

**Anywhere in your app**

Use the mongoose object to access the model of your choice and add a method. You can make the model name and the function name a variable, if you'd like:

```
if (!mongoose.models['model']['fn2']) {
    mongoose.models['model'].prototype['fn2'] = function() {
        console.log("Yeah!");
    }
}
```

Once this function has been prototyped, simply call the instance function on any document from this model:

```
model.findById(someId).exec(function(err, doc) {
    if (doc) {
        if (typeof doc.fn2 === 'function') {
            doc.fn2(); //writes "Yeah!" to the console.
        }
    }
});
```